# Can't I use variables for time calculations in golang?

Tags: go, time, calc

I'm trying to calculate the time 10 minutes ago.
Why can't I do this calculation with variables (usable for a for loop).
See -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // the time now
    fmt.Println(time.Now())

    // the time 50 minutes ago - WORKS
    diff := (60 - 10) * time.Minute
    newTime := time.Now().Add(-diff)
    fmt.Println(newTime)

    // the time 50 minutes ago - DOESN'T WORKS!
    i := 10
    diff = (60 - i) * time.Minute
    newTime = time.Now().Add(-diff)
    fmt.Println(newTime)
}
```

Why `diff = (60 - i) * time.Minute` doesn't work?
This is the error I'm getting -

```
prog.go:20: invalid operation: (60 - i) * time.Minute (mismatched types int and time.Duration)
```

For Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TJ03K0ULg2

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the error says, you have mismatched types. Convert the integer result to a `time.Duration`:

```
diff = time.Duration(60-i) * time.Minute
```

Answer (score 1):

`time.Duration` actually is type `int64`,so if you want to use variable to make what you want,just declare the variable to `time.Duration`,like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // the time now
    fmt.Println(time.Now())

    // the time 50 minutes ago - WORKS
    diff := (60 - 10) * time.Minute
    newTime := time.Now().Add(-diff)
    fmt.Println(newTime)

    // the time 50 minutes ago - DOESN'T WORKS!
    var i time.Duration
    diff = (60 - i) * time.Minute
    newTime = time.Now().Add(-diff)
    fmt.Println(newTime)
}
```